# How to convert SQL timestamp to a string in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I need to retrieve the MAX(timestamp) value from a SQL table into a string variable but can't figure out how.

So if my table/entity is set up like so:

```
**DEPARTMENTS**
Department  varchar(10) PK
LastUpdated timestamp
```

What would the Linq query look like? I have tried a few iterations but always get an error.

EDIT: Here is an example of what I tried

```
 var result = (from d in _context.LOG_Departments
                      select d.LastUpdated).Max().SingleOrDefault();
```

error: "Cannot implicitly convert type 'byte' to 'string'

**EDIT Solution:**

```
public string MaxDepartment()
    {

        CPLinkEntities _context = new CPLinkEntities();
        var results = _context.LOG_Departments.Max(t => t.LastUpdated);
        string hex = BitConverter.ToString(results);
        hex =  hex.Replace("-", "");
        return hex;
    }
```

Comment: share your code which you tried

Comment: @AshReva, I added an example of what I tried. The timestamp is stored as bunary on the SQL server so it looks like I need to also convert it. Just not that familiar with LINQ.

Comment: Did you try removing `SingleOrDefault()`? `Max()` already gives you single value

Comment: Yes, but since the timestamp is stored as a binary on the server I am now getting the cannot convert type byte to string.

Answer (score 2):

Timestamp is not da datetime thing:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776.aspx

> Is a data type that exposes automatically generated, unique binary
>   numbers within a database. rowversion is generally used as a mechanism
>   for version-stamping table rows. The storage size is 8 bytes. The
>   rowversion data type is just an incrementing number and does not
>   preserve a date or a time. To record a date or time, use a datetime2
>   data type.

You can then use

```
long timeStampLong = BitConverter.ToInt64(value, 0);
```

to get a long back (and convert that long into string if you wish).

Comment: Thanks, I am fully aware of what a timestamp is, I am in fact using it for version control and have since asking the question, found and posted my answer as an edit.

Comment: OK, but converting into string seems strange. You can have strange characters in that string. Probably bad for displaying. And you probably cannot even compare 2 of those strings for greater then or similar.

Comment: I'm using it for version control of lookup tables like Departments (which don't change very often). I am passing the string to a webpage and storing it in local storage, then comparing each page load to it to see if anything in the Departments table  has changed and if so I refresh the local storage hash of Departments. I'm not displaying the value at all. I'm going to be repeating this on may lookups and now need to figure out how to dynamically pass in the table name so I don't have to repeat the code. Should be a pretty slick way of updating lookup dropdowns. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out how to do the conversion.

public string MaxDepartment()
    {

```
    CPLinkEntities _context = new CPLinkEntities();
    var results = _context.LOG_Departments.Max(t => t.LastUpdated);
    string hex = BitConverter.ToString(results);
    hex =  hex.Replace("-", "");
    return hex;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

it could be something like this:

```
yourDBContext context=new yourDBContext();
var maxTimestamp = context.yourTable.Max(t => t.Timestamp);
```

I'd prefer to see [this](http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2008/07/01/10557.aspx) for more detail on working with linq.